# Can’t seed data from my Laravel plugin

Tags: laravel, plugins, seed

I developed a Laravel Plugin, which contains seed data : https://github.com/xoco70/laravel-tournaments

When I try to seed it inside a fresh laravel 5.6 project, with:

```
 php artisan db:seed --class=LaravelTournamentSeeder
```

I get:

```
 ErrorException  : include(/Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/test/vendor/composer/../../database/seeds/LaravelTournamentSeeder.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

When I try to namespace all my seeds file with :

```
 namespace Xoco70\LaravelTournaments\Database\Seeds;
```

and then ruin it with

```
 php artisan db:seed --class=Xoco70\\LaravelTournaments\\Database\\Seeds\\LaravelTournamentSeeder
```

I also get an error:

```
ReflectionException  : Class Xoco70\LaravelTournaments\Database\Seeds\LaravelTournamentSeeder does not exist
```

Inside my plugin, my composer.json is:

```
…
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "Xoco70\\LaravelTournaments\\": "src"
  },
  "classmap": [
    "src/"
  ]
},
…
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I can see in the GitHub code that t[he seeder class is not namespaced neither the other seeding files](https://github.com/xoco70/laravel-tournaments/blob/master/database/seeds/LaravelTournamentSeeder.php). The missing bit is to move the database related code under "src" following the psr-4 entry in the composer:

```
"psr-4": {
  "Xoco70\\LaravelTournaments\\": "src"
},
```

Another alternative is to add another entry in the psr-4 but it might be not clear.

Comment: You are right! Inside my plugin, in composer.json, I added: in psr-4 section: `"Xoco70\\LaravelTournaments\\Database\\": "database"`. But now, I get: `Unable to locate factory with name [default] [Xoco70\LaravelTournaments\Models\Venue].` I don't understand, because Venue model is defined, and namespaced

Comment: I looks like there was a closed issue with a similar background in the repository before https://github.com/xoco70/laravel-tournaments/issues/9. From where are you getting the error (seeding, migration, tests....)? Can you provide more details/trace?